# How to translate restarting and idle message in Spigot with McMyAdmin?

Tags: minecraft

Does anyone know where I can find the strings "Server is restarting" and "You been idle for too long!" in my Spigot Minecraft Server?

I use Spigot 1.8 with McMyAdmin 2.7.0.0 Professional. I opened all .jar files and searched for the strings, but I couldn't find them. I also looked at the files from McMyAdmin. I want to translate these messages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to if McMyAdmin lets you change this in an easy way, but for the "Server is restarting" message, you can simply [edit `spigot.yml`](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-configuration/#messages).  The following messages are all set there:

- You are not whitelisted on this server!
- Unknown command. Type "help" for help.
- The server is full!
- Outdated client! Please use {}!
- Outdated server! I'm still on {}!
- Server is restarting

You can change those ones as you want.

However, for "You have been idle for too long!", it is more difficult as that is actually [a hardcoded string from the vanilla server](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/c1627dc9cc7505581993eb0fa15597cb36e94244/net/minecraft/server/PlayerConnection.java#L69).

It is still changeable, though, since you can intercept the [`PlayerKickEvent`](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerKickEvent.html).  Here's some code you can put into a plugin to do this:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onKick(PlayerKickEvent e) {
    if (e.getReason().equals("You have been idle for too long!") {
        e.setReason("New reason");
    }
}
```

Alternatively I'm sure there is another plugin that implements idle kicks and lets you chose the message (but I don't actually know which).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that